# remove esc function on screen size

Tags: javascript

I have code which enables the esc button to activate the navigation (turns on and off). I don't want it to work if the screen is larger than 768px

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    $('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('show-nav');
    // $('.test').removeClass('mobile-nav');
}
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check for window.outerWidth in your if statement

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 27 && window.outerWidth < 768) {
    $('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('show-nav');
    // $('.test').removeClass('mobile-nav');
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, I was trying to wrap it in another function, this works way better

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 27 && $(window).width() > 768) {
    $('.mobile-nav').toggleClass('show-nav');
    // $('.test').removeClass('mobile-nav');
}
```

in alternbativa you can use BIND and UNBIND functions to enable and disable the event, but I personally do not recommend to you.